# No class exists called CharacterEscapeHandler inside package com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller for jaxb-impl 2.2.11

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I am updating jaxb-impl jar in my application pom to **`2.2.11`** from **`2.1`** .I saw there is no class called CharacterEscapeHandler inside

```
com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller
```

Is there any alternative class for this since our source code uses CharacterEscapeHandler .

I got an alternative from

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxbimpl221jar.htm
```

Can anybody confirm this as the alternative dependency I need to add to support that class from package

```
import com.sun.xml.txw2.output.CharacterEscapeHandler
```

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>com.sun.xml.txw2</groupId>
> <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
> <version>some version</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

```
Ref Link :
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not have used a `com.sun.*` class in your code. These classes are internal JDK implementation classes, that are not part of the standard API and that may change in newer versions of the JDK, as you have found. Using a different `com.sun.*` class will not solve that problem.

Comment: I don't know what `CharacterEscapeHandler` does exactly or what you need it for, but maybe `StringEscapeHandler.escapeXml()` from [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) does what you need.

Comment: Thanks Jesper for your response to answer your  questions,this code was there from long time I mean  its a very legacy one and written to escape characters in soap response from jaxb .Now I cannot go ahead and change the implementation to apache commons text as suggested by you since it may impact other functionalities.If we see the business logic/implementation  from both the packages for the interface i.e CharacterEscapeHandler , reflects the same implementation. Thats why I chose different package .

Comment: If you're really in a situation where you cannot get rid of the use of `com.sun.*` classes, then your solution to use the class from the JAXB 2.2.11 reference implementation will work, but it might break again if you upgrade to a newer Java version which might contain a different version of the JAXB reference implementation.

Comment: Yes I agree with you .Let me reach out  to other folks in my team to change implementation .If they accept it then we are good  else we need to go with new package implementation only.Anyways thanks for your support.Appreciate your swift response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jaxb-impl 2.2.7 the `com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler` was moved to jaxb-core 2.2.7

And since 2.2.10 jaxb-impl lost its dependency on jaxb-core